# JavaScript Event creation with customly attached data

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Is there a JavaScript way to pass custom data to a manually created JavaScript event?

Ok, let's say I got this code to create and trigger a JavaScript event:

```
var evObj = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evObj.initEvent('submit', bubbling, cancelable);
anElement.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

This works fine and can be handled by using this code:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', mySubmitEventHandler, true);
```

But, I need a way to pass additional data to the event, so that `mySubmitEventHandler` knows whether the event was fired by a user or by JavaScript event creation as shown above. A boolean value would be sufficient.

So, how can I add something like "myEvent = true" to the newly created `evObj`?

And please no jQuery answers, I need to do this one in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Attach the parameter to `evObj`.

```
evObj.flag = 'Hi!';
anElement.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

This code demonstrates that the event object passed by [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) is equal to the one in the event listener (**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4e9Lg/)**):

```
var evObj = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
document.body.addEventListener('test', function(e){ alert(e === evObj); },true);
evObj.initEvent('test', true, true);
document.body.dispatchEvent(evObj); // Shows alert, "true"
```

Comment: So easy that it hurts! Thanks alot :)

Comment: `Event.initEvent` is depreciated. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 8):

your evObj it's a normal object you can add any data as a property of the object like evObj.myData = "blablabla"; and then read the data in the listener

Hope this helps

Comment: Similar answer but +1 since this was posted a minute earlier than the above answer!